# .net component for previewing office documents

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, ms-office, document-preview

I have a CMS system written in ASP.NET which among other things allows users to upload documents, typically PDF, powerpoint, Word etc.

I am investigating how to implement a preview function so that once the document has been uploaded it would generate a thumbnail of the first page in the document.

Does someone have an idea what libraries, controls are available to achieve this?

Comment: You probably know this, but don't use the Office applications from ASP.NET.

Comment: If it is any help, the new docx, xlsx, and pptx documents contain a thumbnail.jpeg in the docProps folder.

Comment: JoshRoss - the user will be uploading files and i won't have access to their local drive. Only the file once it's validated and uploaded.

Comment: Any update on this? I also want to implement the preview in my ASP.Net page... Please help me if you can here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Adeptol AJAX DocumentViewer. Very easy to implement and works with over 300 formats.